# How to clear processing memory when closing dialog window?

Tags: qgis

I wrote a simple plugin using Plugin Builder running QGIS 3 buffer process on selected layers/features. It works well, but if the plugin dialog window is closed and re-opened, multiple features get added instead of one (x2, x3, x4, x5, etc, depending on how often the dialog got re-opened).

Does anyone know how to clear the memory layers when the dialog close (X) button is pressed?

```
    def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""

    if self.first_start == True:
        self.first_start = False
        self.dlg = PlugtestDialog()
        self.dlg.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

    self.dlg.layer_comboBox.clear()
    self.dlg.fieldwidth_comboBox.clear()

    # 1/ gets the list of all the layers loaded in QGIS:
    layers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
    layer_list = []
    layer_list.append('')
    for layer in layers:
            layer_list.append(layer.name())

    #adds list of loaded layer to the drop-down
    self.dlg.layer_comboBox.addItems(layer_list)

    # 2/ if layers are loaded, check if there are selected features and select the layer if so. Returns associated fields. 

    selected_layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
    if selected_layer is not None:
        selected_layer_name = selected_layer.name()
        features_count = selected_layer.selectedFeatureCount()
        index_number_selected_layer = layer_list.index(selected_layer_name)

        if features_count is not 0 and selected_layer is not None:
            self.dlg.layer_comboBox.setCurrentIndex(index_number_selected_layer)
            self.dlg.fieldwidth_comboBox.clear()
            selectedComboLayerText = self.dlg.layer_comboBox.currentText()
            selectedComboLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(str(selectedComboLayerText))[0]
            fields = [field.name() for field in selectedComboLayer.fields()]
            self.dlg.fieldwidth_comboBox.addItems(fields)

    # 3/ function to fill the list of field for the selected layer in the layer drop-down. Gets launched when layer drop-down menu changes

    def field_select():
        #self.dlg.field_comboBox.clear()
        self.dlg.fieldwidth_comboBox.clear()

        selectedComboLayerText = self.dlg.layer_comboBox.currentText()
        #conditional to prevent 'list out of range' error in case the empty entry is selected again
        if selectedComboLayerText is '':
            self.dlg.fieldwidth_comboBox.clear()
        else:
            selectedComboLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(str(selectedComboLayerText))[0]
            fields = [field.name() for field in selectedComboLayer.fields()]
            self.dlg.fieldwidth_comboBox.addItems(fields)

    # This connects the function to the layer drop-down when changed. Update fields to show the fields from the associated layer in layer drop down
    self.dlg.layer_comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(field_select)
    self.dlg.fixed_Button.setChecked(True)


    #function to apply a buffer on selected feature
    def buffer_on_selected():

        #selected_layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
        selectedComboLayerText = self.dlg.layer_comboBox.currentText()
        selectedComboLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(str(selectedComboLayerText))[0]

        spinbox_value = self.dlg.spinBox.value()

        if self.dlg.fixed_Button.isChecked() is True:
            buffer_option = self.dlg.spinBox.value()

        #dynamic (by field)
        if self.dlg.field_Button.isChecked() is True:
            field_radius = self.dlg.fieldwidth_comboBox.currentText() 
            buffer_option = QgsProperty.fromExpression(field_radius)

        #dissolved?
        if self.dlg.dissolve_checkBox.isChecked() is True:
            dissolve_option = True
        else:
            dissolve_option = False

        #selected features:
        # Check if features are selected and if tick box is checked
        if selectedComboLayer.selectedFeatureCount() > 0 and self.dlg.only_selected_checkBox.isChecked() is True:


            #if there's already an ouput layer that is loaded, just update the layer:               
            if QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('output'):

                buffer_function = processing.run("native:buffer",{'INPUT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(selectedComboLayerText,True),'DISTANCE':buffer_option,'SEGMENTS':5,'END_CAP_STYLE':0,'JOIN_STYLE':0,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'DISSOLVE':dissolve_option,'OUTPUT':'memory:'})

                sourceLYR = buffer_function['OUTPUT']
                destLYR = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('output')[0]
                features2 = []
                for feature in sourceLYR.getFeatures():
                    features2.append(feature)
                destLYR.startEditing()
                data_provider = destLYR.dataProvider()
                data_provider.addFeatures(features2)
                destLYR.commitChanges()

            #if not, create output
            else:

                buffer_function = processing.run("native:buffer",{'INPUT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(selectedComboLayerText,True),'DISTANCE':buffer_option,'SEGMENTS':5,'END_CAP_STYLE':0,'JOIN_STYLE':0,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'DISSOLVE':dissolve_option,'OUTPUT':'memory:'})
                QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(buffer_function['OUTPUT'])

        #if not, create buffer for all features in the selected layer
        else:

            parameters = {'INPUT':selectedComboLayer,
            'DISTANCE':buffer_option,
            'SEGMENTS':5,
            'END_CAP_STYLE':0,
            'JOIN_STYLE':0,
            'MITER_LIMIT':2,
            'DISSOLVE':dissolve_option,
            'OUTPUT':'memory:'}
            buffer_function = processing.run("native:buffer", parameters)


    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()

    self.dlg.BigButton.clicked.connect(buffer_on_selected)
```

Comment: You should post some code for the main part of your plugin to allow the community to see where the problem could lie. But I would probably suggest that you create/edit a function which gets executed when the dialog closes which deletes any instances of the memory layer (e.g. `del mem_layer` or whatever you named it.)

Comment: I'd really like to clear the memory outputs when the dialog gets closed but I didn't find the right way to do it. What function name does the Close (x) button has? I also can't figure a way to delete if only buffer['output'] exists. What to do to avoid returning an error if no layer exist?

Answer (score 1):

Plugin Builder does check for first_start. All pushButtons should be placed there to avoid multiple launches if the plugin dialog is open/closed multiple times.

`self.dlg.BigButton.clicked.connect(buffer_on_selected)`

should be placed at the beginning of `def run(self):`

`if self.first_start == True:
        self.first_start = False
        self.dlg = PlugtestDialog()
        self.dlg.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.dlg.BigButton.clicked.connect(buffer_on_selected)`  <-----